# Accessing nagios 3 web interface with a Domain name

Tags: apache2, nagios

I am accessing nagios web interface with an ip x.x.x.x/nagios3 but instead I want to access it with a domain name nagios.xyz.com locally first. How can this be done? I have installed nagios 3 apache 2 on ubuntu 16.04 .

Answer (score 0):

IF your Ubuntu have static IP, you can edit your local `/etc/hosts` file and insert this line (I suppose you are using Linux):

```
x.x.x.x    nagios.xyz.com
```

Now you can open `nagios.xyz.com/nagios3` with your browser and get your Nagios web interface.
PS: Anyway, this solution will work only from your PC/NTB.